# Ошибка Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted

Tags: c++

Есть задание
Сжать одномерный массив, состоящий из n вещественных элементов,
удалив из него все элементы, модуль которых находится в интервале [a; b].
Освободившиеся в конце массива элементы заполнить нулями.

Остановился на том чтобы переносить элементы в конец строки, но не могу понять почему выходит ошибка
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1251");
    int arr[10], n, i, j = 0, t = 0, m, a, b, tem = 0;
    srand(time(0));
    cout << "введите размерность массива: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 20;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << "\nвведите интервал который необходимо удалить: ";
    cin >> a >> b;
    for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        arr[i] = 0;

    }

    for (i = a; i < n; i++) {
        if (i++ < n) {
            tem = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i++];
            arr[i++] = tem;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted — значит, что-то рядом испорчено, значит, 99.9% — выход за границы... При каких значениях у вас получается ошибка? Пройдите и посмотрите, нет ли где-то обращения к элементу за пределами `arr`. И еще: забудьте о таких вот фокусах — `arr[i] = arr[i++];`, это работать не будет! Кстати, скорее всего именно тут вы и вываливаетесь за границы массива.

Comment: А как мне тогда обращаться к следующему элементу массива?

Comment: `arr[i] = arr[i+1]`. Инкремент `i++` должен быть только один - в заголовке цикла. Но и это работать не будет. У вас весь код неверный.

Comment: Перед каждым оператором обращения по индексу вам необходимо проверять валидность индекса.

Comment: как его проверить?

Comment: Напишите соотв. логическое выражение и при выходе значения индекса из допустимого диапазона вызывайте std::abort ну или хотя бы напечатайте ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки в представленном коде:

- Сначала создаётся массив из 10 элементов, а затем он начинает заполняться для произвольного значения `n`, то есть, происходит выход за пределы массива для `n > 10`.
- На принадлежность диапазону проверяются НЕ числа, как сказано в условии, а индексы в массиве, для этого используется излишний проход по массиву.

После исправления указанных ошибок, для решения задачи достаточно скопировать все подходящие элементы в начало массива, а затем дописать нули в конец.

Вариант решения ([онлайн демо](https://onlinegdb.com/qkw3MTSCe2)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1251");
    srand(time(0));
    
    int n;
    cout << "Введите размерность массива: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    int arr[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 20;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    int a, b;
    cout << endl << "Введите интервал который необходимо удалить: ";
    cin >> a >> b;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int x = abs(arr[i]);
        if (x < a || x > b) {
            arr[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    while (j < n) arr[j++] = 0;

    cout << endl << "Сжатый массив" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Пример:

```
Введите размерность массива: 15

17 13 12 4 1 14 6 4 14 15 9 4 19 11 12 
Введите интервал который необходимо удалить: 3 13

Сжатый массив
17 1 14 14 15 19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```